# Add static block in right col Magento

Tags: magento

I try to add a static block created in CMS -> static block (id : qualif).
To do this I create a local.xml in app/design/frontend/default/default/layout and I insert :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_qualif" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>qualif</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

But anything appears on my right col.
I've check that my  template is "default" in Admin -> System-> Design.

Have you any solution ?

Comment: first, did you clear cache on layout? second, if you applied theme, try modify xml in theme folder.

Comment: I don't understand ... I modify local.xml in theme folder ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the xml in catalog.xml after the `<default>` tag:

```
<reference name="right">
   <block type="cms/block" name="cms_qualif" after="-">
       <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>qualif</block_id></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

And don't forget to clear cache after you make the changes.

Comment: The store view for the block "qualif" is on "All store views"

Comment: I'm on the version 1.3.0 , and I don't have "Block" in System->Permissions.
I tried to write :
<reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="cms_qualif" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>qualif</block_id> </action>
            </block>
        </reference>

in home page -> custom design -> XML
And it works for the home page ...

Comment: Try to do the same thing for the CMS page via Magento backend.

Comment: I've done it via Magento backend , CMS->pages -> home page -> custom design -> XML

Comment: On which page are you trying to add this block? CMS page, category page, contact?

Comment: I would like to add this block on all pages.